# Catch oledb Exception with a specific error code

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, oledb

I'm trying to catch a duplicate key violation. I can see the System.OleDB.OleDBException in the Intellisense pop up, but the inner exception is null. How do I access the Error Code in the System.OleDB.OleDBException?

Greg

```
try 
{
    MyData.ConExec(sSQL);
}
    catch (Exception ex)
{
OleDbException innerException = ex.InnerException as OleDbException;
if (innerException.ErrorCode == -2147217873)
{
    // handle exception here..
}
else
{
    throw;
}
}
```

Comment: Try catching the OleDBException instead of catching the general Exception.

Comment: The above code may null ref on `innerException.ErrorCode`

Answer (score 2):

don't declare an instance of the exception. It will surely return empty if you do.

```
try
{
    MyData.ConExec(sSQL);
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
    // handle excpetion here...

    if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147217873)
    {

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // if other exception will occur
}
```

Comment: That got it. Thanks. Boy, I've been here before, but it has been a long time since I needed to trap a specific error. Thanks again. Greg